# Are shift op codes really 3 times faster than moves? Intel x86

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

In my Intel x86 Pentium handbook it says that ADD and shifts like SAL/SHR take 1/3 clock compared to things like JMP and MOV that take 1 clock. Is this really true that a bunch of adds and shifts will 3 times faster than a bunch of movs?

I guess I am doubly confused because there is table of "latencies" on the web showing "Pentium M" and none of timings are 1/3, although a few are 1/2. Is this because my book is old and on newer Pentiums shift is the same speed as JMP?

Comment: Original Pentium from 1993? Some things have changed since!

Comment: This is the book I have: http://marketplace.vintage-computer.com/auction_details.php?name=Intel-Pentium-Processor-Family-Developers-Manual-Vol-3-Architecture&auction_id=112800.  This book is the "Intel Pentium Processor Family Developer's Manual Vol 3: Architecture and Programming Manual" dated 1995.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't confuse "latency" with "reciprocal throughput".

- **Latency** is how many cycles it takes to execute one instance of the instruction.
- **Reciprocal Throughput** is how many instructions per cycle that the processor can sustain.

That `1/3` that you are seeing isn't the latency. It's the reciprocal throughput. The processor can sustain 3 ADDs per cycle. (if they are all independent) But each one still takes at least 1 cycle to execute.

If you have latency `1` and reciprocal throughput of `1/3`, that means that the processor can execute up to 3 ADDs simultaneously. But each one still takes 1 cycle.

---

Historically, most Intel processors (since Pentium?) have 3 main execution units that can all do basic operations such as additions and shifts. That's why most of these are `1/3` reciprocal throughput.

Register-to-register MOVs should also be `1/3`. But MOVs that touch memory (ie. loads and stores) are historically only 1/cycle. (Recently with Sandy Bridge and later, this has been increased.)

Comment: “since Pentium?” Architectures have changed completely several times since the Pentium, although all changes in Intel processors going back to the Pentium M seems to be rather evolutionary, according to http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is about the original Pentium (i.e., not a Pentium Pro or newer) the `1/3` does not mean "one third" (or anything like it). It means the instruction has 1 cycle throughput and 3 cycle latency (i.e., you can start one instruction every cycle, and one can finish every cycle, but the instruction takes three pipeline stages, so there's a three-cycle delay between starting and finishing a particular instruction).

The original Pentium had only two execution units and no out of order execution. In a given clock cycle, the next instruction would execute in the U pipeline. If the right conditions were met, the instruction after that could execute in the V pipeline. Under no circumstances did more than two instructions execute in any given cycle, and under no circumstance did more than one instruction execute per clock in a single pipeline.

Later processors (starting with the Pentium Pro) added out of order instruction scheduling, and the ability to execute more than two instructions in a single cycle (could have considerably more "in flight" but was limited to retiring three per cycle). The Pentium IV added the ability to execute 2 extremely simple instructions (register to register AND, OR, NOT, ADD, SUB, single-bit shift) in the same execution unit in a single clock cycle (i.e., it had an execution unit that was actually running at double the rated clock speed, so for example, on a 2.8 GHz processor a small amount of the circuitry was actually running at 5.6 GHz).

Comment: Okay, so are you saying the 1/3 means that a given ADD/SHR will always take at least 3 clocks to execute? If so, this would apparently mean that the ADD/SHR is slower than the JMP/MOV, which would make sense I think.

Comment: @TylerDurden: yes, that's pretty much it. I seem to have a vague memory of a typo in a manual around that time, where something was shown as 1/3 that should have been 1/2 though (i.e., what was shown as three cycle latency was really only 2).